# Does ProcessBuilder() take some time to complete?

Tags: java, processbuilder

Does ProcessBuilder() take some time to complete?
For example, some `key` is already defined for the OS you are using.
Is it possible that when the second line executes the previous step isn't yet completed? (the second line will be using `old key`)

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("cmd.exe", "/c", "setx key abcd").start();
util.encode(); // it uses a `key` defined in previous line
```

Comment: 'Building' takes very little time.  Execution (as a result of the 'start' call) takes as long as it takes the command to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely takes some time (whatever time your command takes). The start method returns a Process, which you can wait for:

```
var process = ProcessBuilder().command("cmd.exe", "/c", "setx key abcd").start();
try {
    process.waitFor();
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
util.encode();
```

EDIT: in addition it is not clear that this will work the way you think it will. The system environment variable that you create may not be set for old/running processes such as your own; quite possibly it applies only to new ones. You'll notice soon enough, but if it doesn't work even with wait that may be the reason.

Comment: didn't thougt about it, even after `wait` when I get the env value of `key` it returns the old value....